# CSS z-index property

Tags: html, css, z-index

Really hoping someone can help a z-index novice.

I'm trying to position a div on top of everything else on my page:

http://www.designbyantony.com/bipf/index.html

The div (you can probably see the problem) is the roun blue circle with 'March 6-8 2015'.
I'd like it to sit on top of everything else properly - ie: run over the nav bar a bit and chip over the area which has the repeating 'arch' design.

I've tried using z-index but I'm obviously going wrong somewhere.

**CSS** is at

http://www.designbyantony.com/bipf/styles.css

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` in the `#page_content` in `styles.css` at Line **`245`**:

```css
#page_content {overflow: visible;}
```

Or if you would like to have clearing after the `#page_content`, you can use something like this:

```css
#page_content:after {display: block; clear: both; content: " ";}
```

**Reason:** The parent of `#dates` is been cropped by `#page_content`, which has `overflow: hidden`, that doesn't allow contents to be hanging.

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it brought the graphic to the front as I wanted but its messed up something else. The large graphic at the bottom of the page is shunted up to the top behind the header. Any ideas? Antony

Comment: @AntonyAntoniou That's what I have given the second CSS. It is used for clearing the floats. It worked. Please check by including the second CSS too!

Comment: @AntonyAntoniou Added a preview too! Check it out.

Comment: Hi Praveen - sorry I missed that last bit of CSS. Where do I add this?

Comment: #page_content:after {display: block; clear: both; content: " ";}

Comment: In the styles.css file or the html?

Comment: Parveen - thank you so much. That worked a treat - I've uploaded the files so you can see. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

Change into your CSS like that.Remove the both position:relative from CSS

```
#page_content {
width: 970px;
margin: auto;
height: auto;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
/* position: relative; */
background-color: #FFFFFF;
overflow: hidden;
/* position: relative; */
z-index: 2;
 }
```

and again change your CSS of #dates.remove left position left:1046;top: 171px;[image] and put there right:0

```
 #dates {
position: absolute;
left: 1046px;
top: 171px;
z-index: 10000;
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
display: block;
 background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gautam - thanks for responding. I tried this and yes its brings the graphic to the front. Problem is that the blue graphic is now fixed in the viewport. I need it to always sit in the same position relative to the page content. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

it's not a z-index problem. your div id="dates" actually cropped by your div id=page_content

Answer (score 1):

Change overflow from hidden to visible for #page_content in styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Z-index works, it's `overflow:hidden` in combination with `position:relative` for `#page_content` that causes clipping. The easiest way to fix this, IMO, is to add another `div` wrapper inside `#page_content` and to move `overflow:hidden` to this inner `div`. Without `position:relative`, `overflow:hidden` will not clip absolutely positioned descendants of this `div`, and the page will look as planned.

Comment: Ilya - thank you for responding. I've maanaged to rectify the problem using Parveens help. Thanks again - Antony